# How to turn off zeroconf in Ubuntu?

Tags: zeroconf, avahi

There's this thing called
[zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)
and I have zero need for it in my computer.

How do I disable it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Remove the
[`avahi-autopid` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=avahi-autoipd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

And reboot.

Comment: That would be *avahi-autoipd*